# Jquery issue with changing classes

Tags: jquery, css, dom

I'm creating a small box on one of my pages which will toggle between 3 different outputs based on the active tab. I set the left-most tab to be active upon loading and when the others are clicked this active tab becomes ordinary and the clicked tab becomes active. I created two classes, one called `activeBoxTab` and `boxTab` which are toggled between as you can see in the jsfiddle below. My issue is that whichever tab is set as the default active, becomes useless once another tab is clicked yet the other two can be clicked back and forth.

http://jsfiddle.net/rxYB7/2/

HTML:

```
<div id="boxTabs">
    <p class="boxTab" id="deliveryTab">Tab 1</p>
    <p class="activeBoxTab" id="returnTab">Tab 2</p>
    <p class="boxTab" id="careTab">Tab 3</p>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".boxTab").click(function () {
        $(this).siblings(".activeBoxTab").attr('class', 'boxTab');
        $(this).attr('class', 'activeBoxTab');
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: I can't see a link to your jsfiddle...

Comment: Some code to see what did you tried?

Comment: woops! i forgot to include link.. added now!

Comment: Your fiddle does not work because you have not included jQuery. Here is a "working" demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rxYB7/3/.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I have?

Comment: The select box in top left corner says "No library (purse JS)". So no, you haven't.

Comment: Oh i see, my bad. I thought it automatically had it enabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only bind the event handler to elements with class `boxTab`. But in your HTML, the "selected" element only has the class `activeBoxTab`. The event handler is never bound to that element and thus nothing happens when you click on it!

Just give it the `boxTab` class as well:

```
<p class="activeBoxTab boxTab" id="returnTab">Tab 2</p>
```

and change your event handler to:

```
$(this).siblings('.activeBoxTab').removeClass('activeBoxTab');
$(this).addClass('activeBoxTab');
```

Comment: I'll mark this as correct as it is pretty much how i've done it now. Cheers for that, also as a novice with jQuery/JavaScript i didn't know i needed to bind an event handler upon load, which explains why i couldn't find a way round it.

Comment: Yes, event handlers can only be bound to elements which exist. `$(".boxTab")` will find all elements with the class `boxTab` and then `.click` will bind the event handler to all found elements. Adding the class to an element later on does not magically add the event handler as well. Due to the way how events work in browsers, you can use *event delegation* to handle events on element that might not exist yet at the moment the handler is bound. But in that case you are not binding the handler to the elements directly but to an ancestor of them. Have a look at: http://learn.jquery.com/events/.

Comment: Ah i understand, i definitely feel in the case of using tabs it is much easier to add the class that makes the tab stand out alongside the general styling class that applies to all tabs. Makes it easier to know what im doing along the way.

Comment: Certainly. There is no reason not to include the `boxTab` class from the beginning, since it is a tab after all (and *additionally* it is selected). Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

You're only binding the click handler to the boxTab tabs and the originally active tab isn't a boxTab. You need to bind the click handler to both:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".boxTab, .activeBoxTab").click(function () {
        $(this).siblings(".activeBoxTab").attr('class', 'boxTab');
        $(this).attr('class', 'activeBoxTab');
        return false;
    });
});
```

Fixed fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rxYB7/4/

The does however mean that the click handler will fire when you re-click the currently active tab. If you want to avoid that you can check and abort in the click handler or use a live event check using '.on' to dynamically set the click handlers based on current class for all elements within the containing div.

Answer (score 0):

Your first `activeBoxTab` has no click event. Thats why it's not working. You have to add both classes `boxTab activeBoxTab` to handle the event in that tab. Then you must remove or add `activeBoxTab` class.

```
<div id="boxTabs">
    <p class="boxTab" id="deliveryTab">Tab 1</p>
    <p class="boxTab activeBoxTab" id="returnTab">Tab 2</p>
    <p class="boxTab" id="careTab">Tab 3</p>
</div>
<div id="productInfoBox">
    <p class="activeBoxInfo" id="deliveryInfo"></p>
</div>

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".boxTab").click(function () {
        $('.activeBoxTab').each(function(index, value) {
            $(value).removeClass('activeBoxTab');
        });
        $(this).addClass('activeBoxTab');

        return false;
    });
});
```

[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rxYB7/6/)

Comment: You don't have to use `.each`. You can just do `$('.activeBoxTab').removeClass('activeBoxTab');`.

Comment: Simplistic as it is, his original class handling does work. And IMO you should only remove the class from the sibling tabs in the container rather than globally across the page.

Comment: If you do `.each` you can do more specific things, such `if (index % 2 === 0){...}`. For example, change background color or whatever you want (change texts, etc...). I think this is a better working function. Answering you, Rup, you can be more specific. This is just an example.

Comment: Of course you can do more things, but it is not needed here. Don't make it more complicated than it has to be.

Comment: @FelixKling It isn't (?). I must add that is more understandable than using `.removeClass` only. You can let jQuery do all the work, but are some things that you should take control of them.

Comment: I've just simply made it so when one of the tabs is clicked it checks for siblings with the class `activeTab` and removes that class, then i used `$(this).addClass('activeTab');` and my issue was resolved.

Comment: We can agree to disagree. I find `$('.activeBoxTab').removeClass('activeBoxTab');` easier to understand than `$('.activeBoxTab').each(function() { ... });`. And since jQuery will call `.each` *internally* anyways, there is no need to call it explicitly. But to everyone their own style.

Comment: @FelixKling Your answer also works. I'm just pointing that you can control what is going to do when it goes on each element and you can specify more things to do. If not, you will have to call many times `$('.activeBoxTab').method()`. I just give a suggestion about controling elements and don't let frameworks that do all the job for some people that probably reads this and has no idea about programming and how it is working internally.

Comment: @LeeB But siblings is getting `.activeBoxTab` elements in a similar way as doing `$('.activeBoxTab')`. Also, you are getting elements by `.activeBoxTab` to do `$(this).siblings('.activeBoxTab')` later. Explain me that O.o Get the element with `'activeBoxTab'` class from elements that I already got by `'activeBoxTab'` class?

Comment: I've changed the code, it is now removing the `activeTab` class from any of the 3 tabs which it is attached too and then adds it to the tab that has been clicked. It's solved the issue i was having so it'll do for me, the only thing i need to solve now is performing a check to link the correct tab to the correct set of information..